# How to replace file from existing RPM package?

Tags: linux, fedora, redhat, rpm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use rpm to update/replace existing files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722305/how-do-i-use-rpm-to-update-replace-existing-files)

Suppose I have an already installed RPM package on my system. I want create another package which can overwrite some files of that existing package. How could I do that? Note that this is not an upgrade. Simply some modules (packaged in RPM) share some configure files. Each time a module is updated, the configure files needs to be updated as well. All modules share the same configure files.